# $wpdb->get_row returns column name instead of column value

Tags: plugins, wpdb

Below is my Code

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'aorborc_session';
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_aorborc_session (session_str) VALUES (UUID())");
$last_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$session = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT 'session_str' FROM ".$table_name."  WHERE id = ".$last_id);
return $session->session_str;
```

The output is **session_str** instead of the mysql UUID value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: should be `"SELECT session_str FROM "` without the quotes around session_str